# How to crawl social websites without using API?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

I would like to gather data from social websites such as Pinterest, Twitter or Facebook. I know some of them (such as Twitter) has offered API, but I do not want to use the API since it may have many shortcomings. My question is how to directly scrape/crawl these social websites?

I know how to do simple crawling for general websites. But the first problem when trying to crawl the social websites is that I need to log in. Do anyone knows how to tackle this?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is super against pretty much all of their service agreements.

But if you are set on doing it there are basically 2 routes you can go

1) You can create an actual crawler which for all intents and purposes is you creating a web browser.  Then you manage your cookies etc... so you have logins that way. This is usually easier for them to detect though you can be smart bout it.

2) You can create some kind of automation software that simulates users clicking or whatnot.  I've had some success with this one and since users are being simulated as long as you aren't mining too fast.

Answer (score -1):

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client libraries like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) gives you the ability to programmatically get and use cookies and do `POST` requests, so you should (in principle at least) be able to mimic in your program what is happenning when you browse such sites.

Of course, these sites could change, and you'll have to adapt.

Perhaps using [ICAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol) (e.g. thru some specially configured Squid proxy) might be relevant also.